# schunk_svh_driver : grasps

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, can I read the values of the current or of contact force and decide to stop the hand if it touches an object?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208094/schunk_svh_driver-:-grasps/) by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2015-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

~CHANNEL_NAME/current_controller (vector of floats, default: see yaml files)

```
Parameters used for the hardware current controller. See additional documentation in YAML files and below. If no values are provides the current will use safe internal defaults.
```

---

Originally posted by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) with karma: 406 on 2015-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on 2015-04-28**:
I used the values in Yaml file but they are the parameters used to control. I want to read the current value of current/force. Is it possible?

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-28**:
seemed that reading the actual current value is not possible, best would be a topic, but there is none

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-28**:
perhaps you can get the svh firmware and add a topic publisher which publishes these values